# how to disable date picker from today to next two days using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

the current code just disable the date before today. i need the calendar to disable 2 days after today.

```js
let dateInput = document.getElementById('pick_date');

const cur_date = new Date();
const cur_month = cur_date.getMonth() > 9 ? cur_date.getMonth() + 1 : '0' + (cur_date.getMonth() + 1);
const cur_day = cur_date.getDate() > 9 ? cur_date.getDate() : '2' + cur_date.getDate();
const dateStr = cur_date.getFullYear() + '-' + cur_month + '-' + cur_day;

dateInput.setAttribute('min', dateStr);
```

```html
<input type="date" class="textbox" id="pick_date" name="pickup_date" />
```

Comment: Then just add 2 days on `cur_date`

Comment: you can use min, max attribute of htm5 date .https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/date

Comment: @HarshMishra OP knows this already: `dateInput.setAttribute('min', dateStr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
let dateInput = document.getElementById('pick_date');
const cur_date = new Date();
cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() + 3);
var dateStr = cur_date.toISOString().split("T")[0];;
dateInput.setAttribute('min', dateStr);
```

```html
<input type="date" class="textbox" id="pick_date" name="pickup_date" />
```